# use component variable in scss style

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this kenburns gallery slideshow which I did statically and I would love to make it more dynamic now ...

so I have this component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="slideshow">
      <v-img v-for="photo in photos" :key="photo.id_photo" :src="photo.full_img_path" class="slideshow-image"></v-img>
    </div>
    <Header></Header>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './shared/Header.vue';
import PublicService from './public.service';
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    Header
  },
  data: () => ({
    serverHost: process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL,
    photos: []
  }),
  created() {
    this.getHomePagePhotos();
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    getHomePagePhotos() {
      PublicService.getHomePagePhotos().then(
        result => {
          this.photos = result?.data;
          this.photos.forEach(p => {
            p.full_img_path = this.serverHost + p.photo_path.replace('/uploads', '') + '/' + p.photo_name;
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
$items: 4;
$animation-time: 4s;
$transition-time: 0.5s;
$scale: 20%;

$total-time: ($animation-time * $items);
$scale-base-1: (1 + $scale / 100%);

.slideshow {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  animation-name: kenburns;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: $total-time;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale($scale-base-1) translateX(500px);

  @for $i from 1 through $items {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      animation-name: kenburns-#{$i};
      z-index: ($items - $i);
    }
  }
}

@for $i from 1 through $items {
  @keyframes kenburns-#{$i} {
    $animation-time-percent: percentage($animation-time / $total-time);
    $transition-time-percent: percentage($transition-time / $total-time);

    $t1: ($animation-time-percent * ($i - 1) - $transition-time-percent / 2);
    $t2: ($animation-time-percent * ($i - 1) + $transition-time-percent / 2);
    @if ($t1 < 0%) {
      $t1: 0%;
    }
    @if ($t2 < 0%) {
      $t2: 0%;
    }

    $t3: ($animation-time-percent * ($i) - $transition-time-percent / 2);
    $t4: ($animation-time-percent * ($i) + $transition-time-percent / 2);
    @if ($t3 > 100%) {
      $t3: 100%;
    }
    @if ($t4 > 100%) {
      $t4: 100%;
    }

    $t5: (100% - $transition-time-percent / 2);
    $t6: (($t4 - $t1) * 100% / $t5);

    #{$t1} {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale($scale-base-1) translateX(($i * 72px % 200px)-100px);
    }
    #{$t2} {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    #{$t3} {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    #{$t4} {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: scale(1);
    }

    @if ($i != $items) {
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale($scale-base-1);
      }
    }

    @if ($i == 1) {
      $scale-plus: ($scale * (100% - $t5) / $t4);
      $scale-plus-base-1: (1 + ($scale + $scale-plus) / 100%);

      #{$t5} {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale($scale-plus-base-1);
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

And I wonder how do replace the very first scss variable

```
$items: 4;
```

with the actual number of items coming from the server

```
$items: this.photos.length;
```

I googled a lot but didn't find anything .. any idea?

Comment: Are you using Vue 3? And if your answer is yes, have you tried `v-bind`? Here is the [related link](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css)

Comment: unfortunately not :( vue2 ...

Comment: You can't. SASS and JS variables don't exist at the same time. You can't write styles the way you did it with dynamic items value. It's not obvious that these style modifications are required for the library you use. If you believe they really are you likely picked the wrong one.

Comment: it's not a library... I wrote it myself... so I am thinking I would have to rewrite it :))) thx for the confirmation

Comment: Why not to use inline style

Comment: @Emir how would it help? the key variable I need to dynamically update is the `$items` ... how would the inline style solve this?

Comment: sorry, was wrong. i don't think that's possible

Answer (score 1):

As others have said I don't believe it's possible to set SASS variables in Vue 2. You can set CSS variables however I'm not sure if it's possible to implement those into what you're trying to achieve

https://shayneo.com/blog/binding-css-variables-with-vue/

Comment: yeah I guess I just need to rewrite it completely to make it dynamic :)